# Pressure-temperature diagram in CoolProp 6.4.1

Tags: python, julia, diagram, pycall

How to show the Refrigerants R-410A Pressure-temperature diagram in all its details with CoolProp 6.4.1.
[image]
Not at the level of detail shown in the figure.
With some :
Constant pressure lines-isobars,
Pressure lines,
Temperature lines,
Constant entropy lines, isentropic,
...

Comment: Hey, this question really needs more detail. Exactly what are you trying to do, what isn’t working, what are relevant links?

Comment: [what isn’t working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66989289/warnings-warn-when-generating-the-p-h-diagram-with-coolprop-6-4-1?noredirect=1#comment118429592_66989289)

Comment: Perhaps close this question on favor of the other is it’s the same