# warnings.warn when generating the p-h diagram with Coolprop 6.4.1

Tags: python, julia, pycall

When running the script I show:

```
using PyCall
pyimport("sys").executable
@pyimport CoolProp.CoolProp as CP
@pyimport CoolProp.Plots as CPP 
#=UNIT_SYSTEMS = {'EUR': <CoolProp.Plots.Common.EURunits object>, 
'KSI': <CoolProp.Plots.Common.KSIunits object>, 
'SI'
=#

plot = CPP.PropertyPlot("R410A", "ph", unit_system="KSI")
plot.title("R410A log p-h Diagramm")
plot.set_axis_limits([90, 550, 0, 15000])
plot.xlabel("h kJ/kg]")
plot.ylabel("P [kPa]")
plot.calc_isolines(num=15)
plot.show()
```

I get a lot of alerts; some sample of them:

```
       ...
C:\Users\hermesr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\CoolProp\Plots\Common.py:596: UserWarning: An error occurred for inputs 0.928571, 264.413011 with index (111,): For pseudo-pure fluid, quality must be equal to 0 or 1.  Two-phase quality is not defined
  warnings.warn(
C:\Users\hermesr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\CoolProp\Plots\Common.py:596: UserWarning: An error occurred for inputs 0.928571, 264.993308 with index (112,): For pseudo-pure fluid, quality must be equal to 0 or 1.  Two-phase quality is not defined
  warnings.warn(
C:\Users\hermesr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\CoolProp\Plots\Common.py:596: UserWarning: An error occurred for inputs 0.928571, 265.573604 with index (113,): For pseudo-pure fluid, quality must be equal to 0 or 1.  Two-phase quality is not defined
  warnings.warn(
C:\Users\hermesr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\CoolProp\Plots\Common.py:596: UserWarning: An error occurred for inputs 0.928571, 266.153901 with index (114,): For pseudo-pure fluid, quality must be equal to 0 or 1.  Two-phase quality is not defined
 ...
```

Can you tell me why this alert is due and how to solve the problem?

[image: warnings.warn]

Comment: It sounds like a CoolProp warning/issue rather than a Julia or Python one.

Comment: Looks like the error message comes from the CoolProp library when attempting to compute thermodynamic properties of a pseudo-pure fluid (such as R410A) in the two-phase region with a vapor quality not equal to 0 or 1.